# In emacs shell and eshell, \r erases the entire current line

Tags: shell, emacs, terminal, eshell

In an emacs `shell` terminal window, running *bash*, an input of `\r` moves the insertion point to the start of the line, as expected, but it also erases all data which was on the line. This isn't what I would normally expect from a Terminal.

I understand that `shell` is not as "complete" as some other terminals, but emacs `term` and `ansi-term` can handle this issue, so it doesn't seem to be an inate limitation of emacs.

`eshell` also behaves like `shell`.  Is there some way to tweak this for *shell* and/or *eshell*, so that the following command produces `cb` and not just `c`

```
printf "ab\rc\n"    

#                   gnome     emacs  emacs      emacs  emacs 
# terminal:  xterm  terminal  term   ansi-term  shell  eshell`   
# output:    cb     cb        cb     cb         c      c
```

Using: GNU Emacs 23.1.1 in Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: printf $(echo 'ab\nc\n'  | tr '\r' '\n')

probably not yet what your are looking for

Comment: @AndreasRöhler: The issue in queston is that of changing how the terminal interprets and modifies the input, rather than how to provide different input.